# Can't I create non-persistent object on Realm for Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, realm

I'm making app with using Xamarin.forms and Realm for Xamarin.

I often create object based on Realm but I use just new MYCLASS instead Realm.GetInstance ().CreateObject.
Because it's a object that I don't want to store.

For object I want to store, of course I used CreateObject within Write().

It worked very well before 0.77.1.
I updated to 0.77.1 and there is weird runtime error that says "Attempted to access detached row". And I debug it and object is ruined when original(stored one)'s property is modified by copy one.

I think it might cause that error. 
But Why?

I can't not use it that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to upgrade to latest version (0.77.2). Seems the problem is gone, at least for me :-)

Comment: Thanks, I will try. But I prefer use package from nuget gallery instead of Github.

Comment: I had to downgrade and it's fine now. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Oh, Shoot. Then, I lost my yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

The detached row exception should only happen when you access an object that was managed (i.e. either created with `Realm.CreateObject<>()` or one that was created with `new` and subsequently `Realm.Manage()`'d), and then detached either because the realm was closed or because the object was deleted.

If yo are getting the exception when working with a standalone object, it's possible that you have discovered a bug. Is it possible for you to create a simple test project that replicates the problem that you could perhaps put in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues)?

Comment: It's fixed on newest version, which is on today.